# Error Installing Azure BizTalk Services SDK (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, sdk, biztalk-services

I've started a BizTalk Service in the Azure Portal and downloaded the SDK from there, I'm trying to install Windows Azure BizTalk Services SDK into my Visual Studio 2015 instance and this error keeps appearing.

Any advice? Solution?

I've added the error window and its log file below.

Thank you in advance.

[Error Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfnZm.jpg)

Comment: how can i add the Log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Biz talk is currently available only for Visual Studio 2012 only and not for hight version of VS.

Comment: But still Microsoft has BizTalk tutorials at learn.microsoft.com that requires this extension. Impossible to follow the tutorial now, but they don't update it or remove it. Same issue with a pluralsight course now.